# Show All Sharepoint List Items in Infopath Form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I was wondering how I can pull the sharepoint list items data and display it in the Infopath form. I have a feeling I will have to use the repeating table but can't seem to figure it out/find tutorial. I'd like to display columns, ex. "Book Title", "Author", "Notes" and have it just pull data and make rows automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, once you make a data connection to your sharepoint list library, you just set it as the repeating table properties.

1. Double click on "Repeating Table"
2. Change Binding
3. Select the data source then select the FOLDER that contains the columns data, then next
4. Add the columns you want to display and your done.
5. Preview to double check